# How do I implement default shortcuts in an vsto Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I am struggling with implementing the basic shortcuts for my vsto Outlook add-in. However I need at the very least to be able to **paste** text into a combobox that is in a small forms window that appears in the preview pane of the mail.

I was able to implement the paste function with only 'ctrl' or only 'v' pressed
I have tried everything I found on the internet and even got the functionality working in a test windows forms project with:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
            {
                comboBox1.Text = "success";
            }
        }
```

However when I try the same code in the outlook vsto project this does simply not work. Did anybody have the same or a similar problem? How did you fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Combobox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#combobox) control from the Fluent UI doesn't provide the `KeyDown` event. The best what you can do is to implement ribbon callbacks: `getText` and `onChange`.

The `onChange` callback is called when the value in the edit box is changed and committed by the user.

The signature of the callback should like the following one:

```
C#: void OnChange(IRibbonControl control, string text)
VBA: Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
C++: HRESULT OnChange([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [in] BSTR *pbstrText)
Visual Basic: Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
```

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However I generated the eventhandler with the event properties from visual studio.. Also I was able to implement the paste function with only the control key or only the 'v' key pressed. Also I don't use the ribbon, but I have a small forms window in the preview pane of the mail. I will edit this info in my post, sorry for the missing info.

Comment: The OP means a combo box on a form, not on a ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook eats some key strokes. The only way I could work around that is by installing a keyboard hook (`SetWindowsHookExW(WH_GETMESSAGE,...)`) and forwarding the appropriate messages directly to my controls.